# Multi guards authentication VS User Type authentication

Tags: database, laravel, authentication

I'm wondering about which approach is better using **multi auth with guards and different auth tables** Or using the **same auth table with different roles/Types** in this scenario

let say we have two different users types "doctor" and "patient" each of them has totally different profile data

If we use multi-auth we can set all user's data with auth data in the same table **but** we will repeat ourselves if we have a model that belongs to the two users types let say "Hospital" and we will check on guards everywhere.

On the other hand, if we implement roles or types we have to split profile data into three separate tables one for users auth data(email, pass,..etc) with polymorphic relation with others for user-related data let say (**patient-data** and **doctors-data**)
but we have to join everywhere we use user data.

There may be a better solution and I know that there is no absolute right solution I am looking for an answer based on previous experiences in terms of performance and the possibility of expansion.

Answer (score 0):

I would always go with the roles/permissions way for the authentication part. This way you can just have one way to log in.

You can split the login form or you can use the same form for all roles. Based on their role you can redirect them to another page where they can see their actions. For example, a separate vendor dashboard. You can use different login URLs of course where you only allow users to login with a certain role. This is a small adaption to the current login flow by just checking on the role as well. You can even create your own controller for it if needed.

You can always use middleware or permission based on the current role of the user to determine where they can go or what they can see.

Multi auth always makes it more complex, while in your case you just have users that log in but have different permissions